# Reactjs isomorphic-fetch not working for put method. Takes too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a api where I want to upload a music. I have a put method for this..

```
export function put({url, headers, data}={}){

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log("checking data in api")
        console.log(headers)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

        var myParams = {method: 'PUT', headers: headers, body: JSON.stringify(data)}
        return fetch(url, myParams)

    }
}
```

Here `headers` is working good. I am using same for `get` and `post` and its working fine but for put its giving me `cors` error.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` gives me `base64` music like:

`"data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzAwAAAAARDVRCUE0AAAAEAAAAMTIwVEVOQwAAAAwAAABpVHVuZ…QgRnVndWUgaW4gTWVsZWUAAAAAADIwMDQgMDAwMDBBRkIgMDAwMDBCOTAgMDAwMEZDRjQgMDAM"`

What is wrong in here ??

My api call is taking very long more than 1.5 min... and then it fails giving cors error and `400 bad request`... For other like `get` and `post` it is working..